# How do I make the listview.builder scrollable in the container

Tags: flutter

I have a list view that I want to make scrollable inside a container. However, when I scroll down and release my finger, the list locks back to the top. I tried wrapping the list view in a SingleChildScrollView, but it didn't work. Here's the relevant code:

```dart
// The container that holds the list view
SizedBox(
  height: 501,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        // A button to add a new item to the list
        TextButton.icon(
          onPressed: () { ... },
          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
          label: Text("Add Course"),
        ),
        // The list view that needs to be scrollable
        ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: ...,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) { ... },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: is there any specific reason to use the ListView inside a SingleChildScrollView?

Comment: I just added that in an attempt to fix it. Could that be the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using scroll twice.

[image]

If you want to scroll the `ListView` only, remove the `SingleChildScrollView`. You need to stop one of them. if you want to scroll the `Listview.builder` and `Button` together, add `primary : false` to Listview.builder:

```
SizedBox(
  height: 501,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        // A button to add a new item to the list
        TextButton.icon(
          onPressed: () { ... },
          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
          label: Text("Add Course"),
        ),
        // The list view that needs to be scrollable
        ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          primary: false,
          itemCount: ...,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) { ... },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

You can get more information about `primary` property here:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/primary.html

Comment: It works! but do you know how to make it expand to fit the available space and then scroll when out of space.

Comment: You should add physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics() to SingleChildScrollView. not Listview.builder. for more: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClampingScrollPhysics-class.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the SizedBox widget with a fixed height that wraps the ListView.builder.
2. Remove the SingleChildScrollView widget that wraps the Column widget inside the ListView.builder.
3. Wrap the ListView.builder with a Container widget that has a fixed height.

```
Container(
  height: 500,
  child: ListView.builder(
    ...
  ),
```

Comment: Incorrect! If you use only sizing. Flutter recommends to use SizedBox. Container is universal. Universal means that takes a lot of power. It may affect performance